# PlugIn vs Dependency service in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

hi I read some msdn tutorial on Xamarin form but there is no mention of PlugIn. I am a bit confused as to which one to use.
 Dependency service is used to call the platform Specific Api such as TextToSpeech in iOS and Android. But there are Plugin for Camera, Toast, Location and others. It seems this approach is better. 
I need some confirmation and understanding to clear this confusion.
1.Is PlugIn an alternative to Dependency service? 
for Example , I dont have to use Dependency service for location in iOS and Android if there is a Location-Plugin for Xamarin.forms.

your confirmation will help me on this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `DependencyService` is a method that is built into the Xamarin.Forms library to provide you with a way to implement platform-specific code. More information can be found in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

The plugins, now bundled as [Xamarin.Essentials](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials) (but of course there are much more), actually might use this DependencyService or at least work in a very similar way.

There really is not one answer to choose one or the other. If there is a plugin that does what you need and you feel comfortable using it, then do! If you need something different, you might want to write something of your own.

Always have a good look at the state of the code for a plugin: is it actively maintained? Is it built by someone you would trust, etc.